# Template specialization for char pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, lexical-cast

`boost::lexical_cast` is a great tool but in my application I ran into a limitation in `string -> bool` conversion that is bugging me. I need to convert all strings like `"0"`, `"false"` and `"FALSE"` into `false` and `"1"`, `"true"` and `"TRUE"` into `true`.

`boost::lexical_cast` only support conversion from/to `"0"` and `"1"`. So my idea was to write my own conversion function which seems to work fine:

```
bool str_to_bool(const std::string &str)
{
    if(str == "1" || str == "true" || str == "TRUE")
        return true;
    else if(str == "0" || str == "false" || str == "FALSE")
        return false;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Bad cast from std::string to bool!");
}
```

Now I wan to write a wrapper round `boost::lexical_cast` and write my own template specializations for it. Here is what I've got so far:

```
template<typename Target, typename Source>
inline Target my_cast(const Source& src)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<Target>(src);
}

template<>
inline bool my_cast(const std::string& src)
{
    return str_to_bool(src);
}
```

This works great for integers or std::string but obviously fails for string literals or character pointers:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << my_cast<bool>(1) << std::endl;                    //OK
    std::cout << my_cast<bool>(std::string("true")) << std::endl;  //OK
    std::cout << my_cast<bool>("true") << std::endl;               //Fail! 

    return 0;
}
```

So I tried to write another specialization for `char *` but it fails to compile!

```
//does not compile!
template<>
inline bool my_cast(const char*& src)
{
    return str_to_bool(src);
}
```

What is the correct way to support both std::string and `char *`?

EDIT 1: the title was stupid. Fixed it.

EDIT 2: I borrowed a solution from boost itself. Posted as a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559622/template-specialization-for-char-pointer/6559891#6559891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that works. I got the idea from `boost::lexical_cast` itself:

```
template<class T>
struct array_to_pointer_decay
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct array_to_pointer_decay<T[N]>
{
    typedef const T * type;
};

template<typename Target, typename Source>
Target my_cast_internal(const Source& s)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<Target>(s);
}

template<>
inline bool my_cast_internal(const std::string& src)
{
    return str_to_bool(src);
}

template<>
inline bool my_cast_internal(const char* const& src)
{
    return str_to_bool(src);
}

template<typename Target, typename Source>
inline Target my_cast(const Source& s)
{
    typedef typename array_to_pointer_decay<Source>::type src;

    return my_cast_internal<Target, src>(s);
}
```

The main challenge is to deal with array types. The `array_to_pointer_decay` converts any array type to the corresponding pointer type. The rest is easy now.

Answer (score 2):

If you say this:

```
template<>
inline bool my_cast<bool, std::string>(std::string const & src)
{
  return str_to_bool(src);
}

template<>
inline bool my_cast<bool, const char *>(const char * const & src)
{
  return str_to_bool(src);
}
```

Then at least you can make the following work:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char * const q = "true";
  std::cout << my_cast<bool>(q) << std::endl;               //Fail!
  return 0;
}
```

**Update:** Voila:

```
typedef char FT[5];

template<>
inline bool my_cast<bool, FT>(const FT & src)
{
  return str_to_bool(src);
}
```

Comment: Great. I figured that out too. On VS2010 it compiles even without specifying the template arguments. However, it calls the non-specialized version!

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it for the string literal?

Comment: hehehe nice trick! I guess I should add another one for `char[2]` case (`"0"` and `"1"`). But is there a general way to do that? (OK, I know, I should study `lexical_cast` itself).

Comment: @AS: I had wanted to make it a template on the array size, but you can't partially-specialize functions. Would have to wrap this in a class maybe.

Comment: You are right. However that would be just too complicated for such a seemingly trivial case. I wonder if there is a way to use an override instead of specialization.

Comment: Ah, I take it back. I cannot use overrides since in my code I want to use the `my_cast<bool>` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a `const char*`, not a `const char*&`. The mutable lvalue reference here will only bind to an lvalue, whereas the decay from the array type that the string literal actually is will only produce an rvalue `const char*`, to which you can only bind a const reference.

Comment: hmmm, changing it to `my_cast(const char* src)` does not compile either. Changing it to `my_cast(char * const& src)` compiles but does not get called...

Comment: if I just write `my_cast(const char * src)` I get `'bool my_cast(const char *)' is not a specialization of a function template`. The way `Kerrek SB` wrote it works however.

Comment: @AlefSin: That's because you've gotten the syntax for specializations wrong. You need to look those up separately.

Comment: Well, I knew it got it wrong that's why I asked the question! Anyway, I managed to fix it as explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559622/template-specialization-for-char-pointer/6559891#6559891).

Answer (score 1):

Let me add this as a new answer... a type-erasing version!

**For C++98/03**

```
/* Core caster */
bool str_to_bool(const std::string &str)
{
  if(str == "1" || str == "true" || str == "TRUE")
    return true;
  else if(str == "0" || str == "false" || str == "FALSE")
    return false;
  else
    throw std::runtime_error("Bad cast from std::string to bool!");
}


/* Type erasing scaffold */

struct TypeEraseBase
{
  virtual bool cast() const = 0;
  virtual ~TypeEraseBase() { }
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeEraseImpl : public TypeEraseBase
{
  TypeEraseImpl(const T & tt) : t(tt) { }
  virtual bool cast() const { return boost::lexical_cast<T>(t); }
private:
  const T & t;
};

/* Specializations go here */

template <>
struct TypeEraseImpl<std::string> : public TypeEraseBase
{
  TypeEraseImpl(const std::string & tt) : t(tt) { }
  virtual bool cast() const { return str_to_bool(t); }
private:
  const std::string & t;
};

template <size_t N>
struct TypeEraseImpl<char[N]> : public TypeEraseBase
{
  TypeEraseImpl(const char (& tt)[N]) : t(tt) { }
  virtual bool cast() const { return str_to_bool(std::string(t)); }
private:
  const char (& t)[N];
};

template <>
struct TypeEraseImpl<const char *> : public TypeEraseBase
{
  TypeEraseImpl(const char * const & tt) : t(tt) { }
  virtual bool cast() const { return str_to_bool(std::string(t)); }
private:
  const char * const & t;
};


/* User interface class */

struct my_cast
{
  template <typename T> my_cast(const T & tt)
  : pt(new TypeEraseImpl<T>(tt))
  {
  }

  ~my_cast() { if (pt) delete pt; }

  inline bool cast() const { return pt->cast(); }

private:
  const TypeEraseBase * const pt;
};


// Usage example

int main()
{
  const char * const q = "true";
  std::cout << my_cast(1).cast() << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_cast(std::string("true")).cast() << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_cast("true").cast() << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_cast(q).cast() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Type-traited version, templated return type**

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template <typename T> struct is_string : std::false_type { };
template <> struct is_string<std::string> : std::true_type { };
template <> struct is_string<const char *> : std::true_type { };
template <std::size_t N> struct is_string<char[N]> : std::true_type { };


/* The actual caster class */

template <typename T, bool B> struct to_bool
{
  static inline bool cast(const T & t)
  {
    return boost::lexical_cast<T>(t);
  }
};

template <typename T> struct to_bool<T, true>
{
  static inline bool cast(const T & t)
  {
    const std::string str(t);
    if(str == "1" || str == "true" || str == "TRUE")
      return true;
    else if(str == "0" || str == "false" || str == "FALSE")
      return false;
    else
      throw std::runtime_error("Bad cast from std::string to bool!");
  }
};


/* Type erasing helper class */

template <typename Target>
struct TypeEraseBase
{
  virtual Target cast() const = 0;
  virtual ~TypeEraseBase() { }
};

template <typename T, typename Target>
struct TypeEraseImpl : public TypeEraseBase<Target>
{
  TypeEraseImpl(const T & tt) : t(tt) { }
  virtual Target cast() const { return boost::lexical_cast<T>(t); }
private:
  const T & t;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeEraseImpl<T, bool> : public TypeEraseBase<bool>
{
  TypeEraseImpl(const T & tt) : t(tt) { }
  virtual bool cast() const { return to_bool<T, is_string<T>::value>::cast(t); }
private:
  const T & t;
};


/* User interface class */

template <typename Target>
struct my_cast
{
  template <typename T> my_cast(const T & tt)
    : pt(new TypeEraseImpl<T, Target>(tt)) { }

  ~my_cast() { if (pt) delete pt; }

  inline Target cast() const { return pt->cast(); }

private:
  const TypeEraseBase<Target> * const pt;
};

template <typename Target>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const my_cast<Target> & c)
{ return stream << c.cast(); }


/* Usage */

int main()
{
  const char * const q = "true";
  std::cout << my_cast<bool>(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_cast<bool>(std::string("true")) << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_cast<bool>("true") << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_cast<bool>(q) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, I guess I understand it. However this is not the right solution: it does not extend `boost::lexical_cast` in the sense that it only works for a fixed Target type (`bool`). I want to keep all other conversions that `boost::lexical_cast` does and just modify the way it work for a special case (i.e. `string -> bool`). Btw, Look at my own answer below.

Comment: @AlefSin: OK, I added a type-traited version. It actually works in C++98 after all (you just have to define `true_type` and `false_type`. Making the return type `bool` parametric should be quite possible.

Comment: @AlefSin: You could add a `<template Target>` everywhere if you wanted. We could also add overloads for `operator<<` to get rid of the tedious `.cast()` call.

Comment: Great job! Still it seems to be too complicated. I upvote and bookmark it but I think the `array_to_pointer_decay` trick from `boost` is simpler for this case.

Comment: @AlefSin: Yes, of course, in your case the direct overloads are the most straight-forward solution, and decaying the type is a good idea. I updated my code to have parametric return type now, and the stream operator is overloaded, too. The moral advantage is that you could in principle add types via traits without needing to know the implementation (e.g. when adding wide char support?).